# How do I calculate the distance from a vector $u$ to the span of another vector $v$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $u = \begin{bmatrix}3\\6\\0\end{bmatrix}  v = \begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\2\end{bmatrix}$ and $V = \textrm{span}(\{v\})$.

How do I find the distance from $u$ to $V$?

Comment: Geometrically, what is the span of a single vector in $\mathbb R^3$? Once you know that, you can apply whatever tools you have to solve the "distance from point to ___" problem.

Comment: Honestly, my knowledge of spanning is limited, that's why I asked this question. I understand V spanning v means that it consists of all the linear combinations where the second and third entries are equal and are twice the value of the first entry. But I don't understand how I can find the distance with what I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `dot product`: the orthogonal projection of $u$ onto the span of $v$ is 
$$\operatorname{pr} u=\frac{u\cdot v}{v\cdot v}\,v,$$
so what you're after is the norm of vector
$\;u-\operatorname{pr} u=u-\dfrac{u\cdot v}{v\cdot v}\,v$, i.e. the square root of
\begin{align}\Bigl(u-\frac{u\cdot v}{v\cdot v}\,v\Bigr)\cdot \Bigl(u-\frac{u\cdot v}{v\cdot v}\,v\Bigr)&=u\cdot u-2\frac{u\cdot v}{v\cdot v}\,u\cdot v +\Bigl(\frac{u\cdot v}{v\cdot v}\Bigr)^2\,v\cdot v\\[1ex]
&=u\cdot u-\frac{(u\cdot v)^2}{v\cdot v}.
\end{align}

Comment: Shouldn't you take the square root of that?

Comment: Yes, of course. Freudian slip or laziness to type it? ;o) Thanks for pointing it!

Answer (score 0):

Imagine the triangle made by $u$, $V$, and the altitude dropped from the tip of $u$ (see below):
[image]

One edge of the triangle is $u$, that one we know. Another one is the projection of $u$ onto $V$, which we can compute as $p = \frac{u \cdot v}{|v|^2} v$. The last side is therefore just $u - p$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the projection along $v$ of $u$ is $\frac{ u \cdot v}{v \cdot v} v$.

Show that $u - \frac{ u \cdot v}{v \cdot v} v \perp v$. From this, you can conclude the distance from $u$ to $v$.